# R : Get attribute value from an XML

Tags: xml, r

I have a XML, see sample below

```
<params>
<param id='1'>BEN</param>
<param id='2'>DAN</param>
<param id='3'>RYE</param>
    <param id='3'>RYE</param>
    <param id='3'>RYE</param>
</params>
```

How can I get all the param with attribute id=3?

Below is what I have done so far : xmlinfile is the XML file

```
inxml = xmlTreeParse(xmlinfile, handlers=list("comment"=function(x,...){NULL}), asTree = TRUE)
xmlList = xmlToList(inxml);
params = xmlList$'params'
```

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use function `xpathApply` with argument `xmlValue` (to get the value, otherwise `xmlAttrs` to get the attribute). The path should be given in the following syntax :`"//tag[@attribute='value']"`.

```
a <- xmlParse('<params>
<param id='1'>BEN</param>
<param id='2'>DAN</param>
<param id='3'>RYE</param>
    <param id='3'>RYE</param>
    <param id='3'>RYE</param>
</params>')
xpathApply(a,"//param[@id='3']",xmlValue)
[[1]]
[1] "RYE"

[[2]]
[1] "RYE"

[[3]]
[1] "RYE"
```

Similarly `xpathSApply` will gives you a vector of value when possible:

```
xpathSApply(a,"//param[@id='3']",xmlValue)
[1] "RYE" "RYE" "RYE"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlinfile <- paste(readLines(n=7), collapse="\n")
<params>
  <param id='1'>BEN</param>
  <param id='2'>DAN</param>
  <param id='3'>RYE</param>
  <param id='3'>RYE</param>
  <param id='3'>RYE</param>
</params>
library(XML)
xpathApply(xmlParse(xmlinfile), "/params/param[@id='3']", xmlValue)  
# [[1]]
# [1] "RYE"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "RYE"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "RYE
```